# hyperledger indy connecting to an existing pool

Tags: hyperledger

I am trying to connect to an existing indy pool

Indy-sdk's pool python wrapper in GitHub doesn't seem to have any information about existing pools, but I'm not sure about it

I wonder if connecting to an existing pool is not possible with indy, or if not, how to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed connect to any IndySDK ledger you want. All you need is its genesis file. For instance, here are some Sovrin networks you can connect to:

- Sovrin Mainnet: https://github.com/sovrin-foundation/sovrin/blob/master/sovrin/pool_transactions_live_genesis
- Sovrin Stagingnet: https://github.com/sovrin-foundation/sovrin/blob/master/sovrin/pool_transactions_sandbox_genesis
- Sovrin Buildernet https://github.com/sovrin-foundation/sovrin/blob/master/sovrin/pool_transactions_builder_genesis

Genesis file contains information about network nodes and their bls keys, so your client knows where to connect to them and to verify connection authenticity.

To connect to arbitrary ledger, you just need to supply genesis file to `pool.create_pool_ledger_config` and then actually connect to the pool using `pool.open_pool_ledger`.

Here's a short example:

```py
    # 1. Create ledger config from genesis txn file
    pool_config = json.dumps({"genesis_txn": str(pool_genesis_txn_path)})
    await pool.create_pool_ledger_config(pool_name, pool_config)

    # 2. Open pool ledger
    pool_handle = await pool.open_pool_ledger(pool_name, None)
```

taken from IndySDK Python wrapper demo [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/wrappers/python/tests/demo/test_ledger.py#L13)